# app:preDexDebug exception on debug launch with android studio, when including java library project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have run into a very strange issue with android studio giving me the below exception only when trying to launch a debug session, but the project will compile just fine.
The app project is a very basic one activity project (created with
there wizard) at this point.

The project includes a external java library, which itself compiles just fine.
When I do a clean/rebuild,  everything cleans and compiles perfectly as 
expected. 
Its only when I try to run a debug session, with the library included,
when I get the exception.

When I remove the java library as a dependency, the project launches just fine

I have tried running with --stacktrace/--debug,  but none of the info 
is helpful.

Version info:
Build tools:  23.0.0
Android studio 1.4
Gradle plugin 1.3.1
Gradle 2.2.1

When I take this same java library
and add it as a dependency to a older android project,  everything works fine,
So its something with the new project setup wizard/creation that is causing the
issue.

Has anyone run into this, and or is there something special I need to 
do when adding a java lib to an android project.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)

Answer (score 0):

OK,  I got it solved,  by adding a few exclude lines to my build.gradle file
these jackson libs are part of my java lib, and were causing some kind 
of size conflict when packaging up the apk...  hopefully it won't cause
any other issues.

packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module'
    }